# Can't re-log (autorelog) user to Nativescript Firebase App on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, nativescript, autologin, nativescript-firebase

I'm having problems re-logging the user previously logged in with Facebook or Google Sign In on my Nativescript iOS App. It works good with an email/password re-authentication on iOS.

It seems that the function

```
     firebase.init({
        persist:true,
        onAuthStateChanged: (data: any) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            if (data.loggedIn) {
                AuthService.tokenUid = data.user.uid;
                // this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/splash"])
            }
            else {
                AuthService.tokenUid = ''
            }
        },
        iOSEmulatorFlush: true
    }).then(
      () => {
        console.log("firebase.init done");
      },
      error => {
        console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
      }
    );
```

return {"loggedIn":false,"user":null} when the user re-launch the app after closing it. It seems that the plugin nativescript/firebase ([EddyVerbruggen
/
nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/AUTHENTICATION.md)) might have a problem with the authentication on iOS. There is no problem with Android.

Comment: If you think this is caused by a bug in the plugin, you might have more success by posting a bug on the repo you linked.

Comment: thanks I'll do that